# One-liner to set a variable value using a function and throw if it is falsy

Tags: javascript, json, exception

I find myself using the following pattern a lot when working with json data that may or may not be corrupt:

```js
function getFooId(json) {
  const id = json.foo.id;
  if (!id) {
    throw Error(`foo.id has not been defined`);
  }
  return id;
}
```

This seems overly verbose. I would like a one-liner along the lines of:

```js
function getBarId(json) {
  return json.bar.id? json.bar.id : throw Error(`bar.id has not been defined`);
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: there is noting wrong being verbose.

Answer (score 4):

There's a proposal for [throw expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) that would allow you to do this *really* concisely, but it's still at stage 2 - it hasn't been implemented yet.

Currently, `throw` must be a *statement*, like an `if` statement or a function declaration - it can't be in an expression context. To achieve this, you could alternate the `id` variable with an IIFE, where the first (and only) line of the IIFE throws;

```
function getBarId({ bar: { id }}) {
  return id || (() => { throw new Error(`bar.id has not been defined`); })();
}
```

But I still prefer your first method, it's more readable:

```
function getBarId({ bar: { id }}) {
  if (id) return id;
  throw new Error(`bar.id has not been defined`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also a better way to handle the error

```
  function getBarId({bar:{id}}) {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ id ? resolve(id) : reject(`bar.id has not 
   been defined`)})
   }
```